# How to parse and print fields from CSV data in python

Tags: python, csv

I'm dealing with an application that exports text as as CSV type data. The text is broken up into fields where there was a hard return.  I have been trying to use pythons CSV to restore the text.

This is an example of the text:

```
{"This is an example", "of what I what I have to deal with.  ", "Please pick up th following:", "eggs", "milk", "Thanks for picking groceries up for me"}
```

What is the best way to read this output this text like so:

> ```
> This is an example
> of what I have to deal with.
> Please pick up the following:
> eggs
> milk
> Thanks for picking up the groceries for me
> ```

I have tried a number of ways that just haven't been quite right.

Here is what I am doing so far:

```
import csv
import xlrd
book = xlrd.open_workbook("book1.xls")
sh = book.sheet_by_index(0)
cat = 'Mister Peanuts'

for r in range(sh.nrows)[0:]:
    cat_name = sh.cell_value(rowx=r, colx=1)
    cat_behavior = sh.cell_value(rowx=r, colx=5)

    if sh.cell_value(rowx=r, colx=1) == cat :       
        csv_reader = csv.reader( ([ cat_behavior ]), delimiter=',') 
        for row in csv_reader:

                for item in row:
                        item = item.strip()
                        print(item)
            pass    
    pass
```

So, the actual cell value that is returned for cat_behavior is the following:

```
['{"Mister Peanut spent 3.2 hours with {bojangles} fighting', '  "', ' "litter box was cleaned, sanitized and replaced "', ' " Food was replensished - with the best food possible"', ' ', ' "technician - don johnson performed all tasks"}']
```

I am now trying to take the above and run in through csv.reader to sanitize it and print it to a text file.  I am now trying to make the (item) look normal.

Comment: Replace `for r in range(sh.nrows)[0:]:` with `for r in sh.nrows:`

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv
with open('test') as f:
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        for item in row:
            item=item.strip('{} "')
            print(item)
```

The [strip method](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) removes the specified characters from the left or right end of the string `item`.

Comment: Thanks so much. This did help me move forward. The problem is that the CSV may actually have squiggly brackets and quotations which could be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Please explain what you have got to start with.**

```
x = {"This is an example", ......., "Thanks for picking groceries up for me"}
```

That looks like a **set**. Then you pass `[x]` as the first arg of csv.reader!! That doesn't work:

```
[Python 2.7]
>>> import csv
>>> x = {"foo", "bar", "baz"}
>>> rdr = csv.reader([x]) # comma is the default delimiter
>>> list(rdr)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: expected string or Unicode object, set found
>>>
```

You say "application that exports text as as CSV type data" -- what does "exports" mean? If it means "writes to a file", please (if you can't follow the examples dotted all over the web) give us a dump of the file to look at. If it means "method/function returns a python object", please do `print(repr(python_object))` and update your question with a copy/paste of the print output.

What documentation about the application output do you have?

**Update** after comments and question edited:

You say that the cell value "returned" was:

['{"Mister Peanut spent 3.2 hours with {bojangles} fighting', '  "', ' "litter box was cleaned, sanitized and replaced "', ' " Food was replensished - with the best food possible"', ' ', ' "technician - don johnson performed all tasks"}']

This looks like what you printed after passing the ACTUAL data through the CSV mangle, not the raw value extracted by xlrd, which certainly won't be a list; it would be a single unicode object.

In case  you didn't read it before: **Please explain what you have got to *start* with.**

Do you think it possible to do these:

(1) please do `print(repr(cat_behavior))` and update your question with a copy/paste of the print output.

(2) say what documentation you have about the application that creates the Excel file.

Comment: I am using your xlrd to extract cells from the spreadsheet and then printing those cell values into a text file that someone can actually read. One of the cells that I need to print contains CSV like data. So, I am trying to make that text readable before printing it to the text file.

Comment: I have edited to show what I am actually doing with an actual piece of text from the cell.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to look into [`csv.writer`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.writer) to export data to csv, rather than `csv.reader`.

EDIT: The body and title of question conflict. You're right about using `csv.reader`.You can use `print` in a for loop to achieve the result you are after.

Comment: Thanks, Tim.  I am very close now using that method!

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> s
'{"This is an example", "of what I what I have to deal with.  ", "Please pick up th following:", "eggs", "milk", "Thanks for picking groceries up for me"}'

>>> print s.replace(",","\n").replace("{","").replace("}","").replace('"',"")
This is an example
 of what I what I have to deal with.
 Please pick up th following:
 eggs
 milk
 Thanks for picking groceries up for me

>>> open("output.csv","w").write( s.replace(",","\n").replace("{","").replace("}","").replace('"',"") )
```

Comment: Thanks. I am a newbie to python, but won't this cause a problem if there are nested quotations or curly brackets? This is an unfortunate possibility.

Comment: if you have nested stuffs, then don't use this method.

Comment: There shouldn't be too much nesting in CSV files.